# Images not rendering after deploy

Tags: reactjs, vite, netlify

So I coded my app in `react` js and images show on the local server. But after I deployed my app on `Netlify`, images disappeared.

`<Card.Img variant="top" src="src/images/leo-self.jpg"  className= "image"/> <Card.Body>`

is this the right way? because I see people talking about putting img paths in json file as well, which I have no idea about.

Thanks for your time!

P.s. I'm using `bootstrap`, if you're not familiar with the tags.

> I tried moving images to a different folder in another deploy and it didn't seem to work. So in the previous deploy, my images were inside `assets` folder inside `src` folder. Then I moved it to `public` folder and it stil didn't work. Now I made a separate `images` folder within `src` folder and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Are you using `react-scripts` (via `create-react-app`) or Vite to build your app?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Vite (which I recommend), images are moved to the "dist" directory during the build process.

```
src
  -assets
    -images
      leo-self.jpg

<Card.Img variant="top" src="images/leo-self.jpg"  className= "image"/> <Card.Body>
```

Comment: I am using Vite. What do you mean by dist directory?

Comment: When building with Vite in normal mode, the "src" folder is not present inside the "dist" directory. Consequently, any paths starting with "src" will not be found during the build process. To address this, you should define paths in a way that remains consistent during the build.

Comment: could you share examples, please?